# Loading Images from URL freezes the UI on Windows phone

Tags: url, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, dispatcher

I'm trying to load a list of news from a website, so first I make a request to fetch the news (with the thumbnails), and using the Binding feature, I assign the Fetched news to my list box, which contains the image (ImageUrl).

```
                <ListBox Name="lstNews">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,12,12"  Width="180" Height="180">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"  />
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <StackPanel Background="#AA000000" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="60" >
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

It works fine, but the UI freezes until the images show up. how can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, BitmapImages by default do load on the UI thread, which would cause the blockage.  In your xaml, you should be able to do something like:

```
<ImageBrush>
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation" UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
```

Making sure to specify BackgroundCreation for the CreateOptions.  For more information, I personally found this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/13/off-thread-decoding-of-images-on-mango-how-it-impacts-you-application.aspx) to be quiet useful.

Comment: actually it works now :D thank you, I wonder though how you people get solutions like that lol

Comment: By having similar problems and eventually finding the answers myself :)

Comment: Nice, I have to add something here. This code didnt work for me in the emulator (I dunno why). It only works on the device, which we need. Thats why at the beginning I said it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to make sure that your UI does not freeze when you comment out your ImageBrush line? I believe the automatic conversion creates a BitmapImage from your ImageUrl, which normally loads on a background thread, so your UI thread should not block. It is possible that something else altogether is blocking the UI, like excessive amounts of text that needs to be laid out or your data layer code that feeds the list with the data.

Comment: No, everything works just fine when I remove the image control.

Comment: by the way, I'm using Webclient class to make the http request. Could that make a problem with the UI?

Comment: Which thread does it return on? Is it UI thread or a background thread? (Check with Deployment.Current.CheckAccess()). Not sure if it matters here, but it might. Maybe your images are just too big/numerous for a mobile device...

Comment: BTW, you could try replacing the ImageBrush Background with just a regular Image and see if that changes anything. Possibly ImageBrush forces the creation of ImageSource on UI thread...

Comment: According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8), the WebClient callbacks are executed on the UI thread, and so if you're doing a lot of work in your callback, it could also be blocking as well.

Comment: I've tried to load an image from the resources, it works without lagging.